# varnish-4.1.2 configuration for magento2

Tags: magento2, varnish-4

I am trying to configure varnish-4.1.2 for magento2 CE.I replaced downloded varnish 4 configuraton file to my default.vcl . `/etc/default/varnish` and `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` is configured as follows.

### /etc/default/varnish

```
        START=yes
        NFILES=131072
        MEMLOCK=82000
        DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
        -T localhost:6082 \
        -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
        -S /etc/varnish/secret \
        -s malloc,256m"
```

### /etc/varnish/default.vcl/

```
   vcl 4.0;

  import std;

  backend default {
  .host = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
  .port = "8080";
 .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
  }

 acl purge {
 "xx.xx.xxx.xx";
 }

 sub vcl_recv {
 if (req.method == "PURGE") {
  if (client.ip !~ purge) {
        return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
    }
    if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
        return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern header required"));
    }
    ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
    return (synth(200, "Purged"));
     }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
  req.method != "HEAD" &&
  req.method != "PUT" &&
  req.method != "POST" &&
  req.method != "TRACE" &&
  req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
  req.method != "DELETE") {
  /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
  return (pipe);
}

  # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
  if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
  return (pass);
}

# Bypass shopping cart and checkout requests
if (req.url ~ "/checkout") {
    return (pass);
}

# normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

# collect all cookies
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

# static files are always cacheable. remove SSL flag and cookie
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/.*\.(ico|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|bmp|mp3|ogg|svg|swf|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$") {
    unset req.http.Https;
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

return (hash);
 }

  sub vcl_hash {
  if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
 hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$","\1"));
}

}

sub vcl_backend_response {
if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
    set beresp.do_esi = true;
}

if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
    set beresp.do_gzip = true;
}

# cache only successfully responses and 404s
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
    set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
} elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
    return (deliver);
}

   if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
    set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
   }

   # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
   # images, css and js are cacheable by default so we have to remove cookie             
  if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD"))
   {
   unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    if (bereq.url !~ "\.      (ico|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff|bmp|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|svg|swf|woff|woff2|           eot|ttf|otf)(\?|$)") {
        set beresp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set beresp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
        set beresp.grace = 1m;
    }
}
return (deliver);
  }

  sub vcl_deliver {
  if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
    if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
    }
  } else {
    unset resp.http.Age;
  }

unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
unset resp.http.Server;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;
unset resp.http.Link;
}
```

but I am getting error

> Error: Message from VCC-compiler: Unterminated string at
>   ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 19 Pos 32)
>               return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern header
>   -------------------------------###############################
>
> Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2 VCL compilation failed

How do i solve this issue?